# google areachart cannot access datatable rows

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using google chart API to draw an area chart.
The chart represents an altimetric profile and when I pass the mouse over it, it shows the position (lat and long) from the underlying data table.

So I created my chart:

```
data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById("chart-output"));
```

and draw it:

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

and add an handler for the mouseover event

When the event triggers, I want to get the row from the underlying data source

```
if (event.row != null && event.column != null){

  //data is the chart datasource
  var o = data.D[event.row];
  var sel_x = o.c[0]["coords"]["x"];
  var sel_y = o.c[0]["coords"]["y"];

  ...  //show x, y
}
```

The point is that when the project was first released, last year, everything worked fine and the property `data.D` actually contained the desired value.
But now, I've found that the same property is undefined and the rows array is found in property `data.tf`.

I would expect to gain access to the datasource rows through a getter method, but I cannot find the right one. The datatable method  `ǵetRowProperties(rowIndex)` does not provide any content.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and regards

****EDIT 12/09 ****

@Juvian
Thanks for yr reply, but it's a bit more complicated than that.
My datasource is like this:

```
   {"cols":
    [
     {"id":"distance","label":"Distance","type":"number"},
     {"id":"asfaltocemento","label":"Asphalt/Beton","type":"number"},
     {"id":"rocciaghiaia","label":"Fels/Schotter","type":"number"},
     {"id":"ghiaccio","label":"Eis","type":"number"},
     {"id":"terraprato","label":"Erde/Wiese","type":"number"},
     {"id":"sassolastricato","label":"Stein/Pflaster","type":"number"},
     {"id":"sconosciuto","label":"Unbekannt","type":"number"}],
    "rows":
    [
     {"c":[{"v":0,"coords":          {"x":1296400.1245177952,"y":5885847.104437432,"z":1345.275458520788,"segment_no":0}},{},{"v":1345.275458520788},{},{},{},{}]},
     {"c":[{"v":2.8740587294156668,"coords":{"x":1296395.9416741736,"y":5885847.412533606,"z":1345.4754191288682,"segment_no":0}},{},{"v":1345.4754191288682},{},{},{},{}]},
     {"c":[{"v":17.583008965075226,"coords":{"x":1296374.532888888,"y":5885848.966197753,"z":1346.3169989102385,"segment_no":0}},{},{"v":1346.3169989102385},{},{},{},{}]},
     {"c":[{"v":23.830815143830804,"coords":{"x":1296365.4205057025,"y":5885849.273363226,"z":1346.724445260275,"segment_no":0}}, {},{"v":1346.724445260275},{},{},{},{}]},

     ....
   ]}
```

When I get the event from the graphic, I retrieve the needed values this way:

```
var o = data.tf[event.row];
var sel_x = o.c[0]["coords"]["x"];
var sel_y = o.c[0]["coords"]["y"];
```

I know it's not a good practise to use property (tf) and I should use accessor like getValue(), but using the getValue method I can't access 'coords' object and its subobject.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, data.d is not a public method, so google can make changes to that, you should use public methods instead for consistency.

Try this:

```
var sel_x = data.getValue(event.row, 0); // supposing your x value is in fisrt column
var sel_y = data.getValue(event.row, 1); // supposing your y value is in second column
```

More info here: [Google DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)